# Ao copilar o codigo ele da um erro usando a funcao WHILE em C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int num_key=666;
    do
    {
        puts("\n\n\t*********************************************");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*     Calculador de temperatura             *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*          DIGITE SUA SENHA                 *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*  DIGITE 0 PARA SAIR                       *");
        puts("\t*********************************************");
        scanf("%i",num_key);                    
    }while(num_key!=123);
}
```

Estou com um problema nesse laço while, nao consigo encontrar o problema, toda vem que executo ele da erro e fecha. Conferi e redigitei a logica 2 vezes.

Comment: Vc precisa passar o endereço da sua variável `num_key` no `scanf`, pode ser assim `scanf("%i", &num_key);`

Comment: Grato amigo, escrevi mais de 500 linhas aqui ja e fui esquecer isso, falta de atenção Muito obrigado!

Comment: Publiquei como resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma dica importante é habilitar todos os *warnings* exibidos pelo compilador.

Veja os warnings do seu programa:

[image: warnings imagem]

Veja o primeiro warning, ele esta dizendo que esperava um `int *` ao invés de um `int`, como sua variável `num_key` não é um ponteiro, então é necessário que use o `&` para passar o endereço ao invés do valor para a função `scanf()`, assim o compilador para de dar avisos.

O segundo warning é referente ao retorno da sua função `main`. Esta função sua esta retornando um inteiro, sendo assim é necessário atribuir o

```
return 0;
```

ou

```
return 1;
```

para caso ocorra um erro no seu programa, perceba que o compilador também de alerta a respeito disso.

Seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num_key=666;
    do
    {
        puts("\n\n\t*********************************************");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*     Calculador de temperatura             *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*          DIGITE SUA SENHA                 *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*                                           *");
        puts("\t*  DIGITE 0 PARA SAIR                       *");
        puts("\t*********************************************");
        scanf("%i", &num_key);
    }while(num_key!=123);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: obrigado! vou incluir no meu codigo.